# QR Module of Eigen library is not found, where do I need to alter the Cmake.txt

Tags: ros, eigen3, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy everybody,

I am currently writing a function for a ros node. During this calculation I am trying to use the pseudo inverse of the QR Module of Eigen. But unfortunately it is not able to find the include and by that not the function. I think I need to alter my Cmake file. I did already use normal <Eigen/Eigen> functions so this is not the problem.

I found a stack overflow post in which it seems very easy to use the function. Just for clarity I add the link here: [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465197/eigen-library-pseudo-inverse-of-matrix-matlab-pinv)

Thank you very much for your help. Since I am not posting very often just tell me when I need to change anything. I will add all the information as soon as possible.

The code I am trying to make run:

```
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <algorithm>  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <Eigen/QR> //<- can't find this import

void calc_delta_p(Eigen::Matrix <double,1,6> &delta_p,Eigen::Matrix <double,6,6> &hessian){

hessian.completeOrthogonalDecomposition().pseudoInverse(); //<-cant find this function
delta_p=hessian*delta_p;

}
```

The compiler throws this error:

```
/home/catkin_ws/src/image_publisher/src/function_file.cpp:120:13: error: ‘class Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6>’ has no member named ‘completeOrthogonalDecomposition’
     hessian.completeOrthogonalDecomposition().pseudoInverse();
```

Here is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(image_publisher)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

 ## Find catkin macros and libraries
 ## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
 ## is used, also find other catkin packages
 find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
      cv_bridge
      #opencv2
      roscpp
      sensor_msgs
      std_msgs
      cmake_modules #eigen
      dynamic_reconfigure
       message_generation
       )

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


 ## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
 add_message_files(
   FILES
   sixDOF.msg
 )


## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   sensor_msgs
   std_msgs
 )


## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
  generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
  cfg/dynamic_reconfigure_file.cfg
 )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##

###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if your package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need catkin_package(   INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES image_publisher   CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs dynamic_reconfigure message_runtime
#opencv2
#  DEPENDS system_lib   DEPENDS Eigen #Eigen library )

###########
## Build ##
###########

find_package(OpenCV) find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
#eigenlibrary


set( PROPRIETARY_FUNCTIONS_H include/image_publisher/function_file.h )

set( PROPRIETARY_FUNCTIONS_CPP src/function_file.cpp )
## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations include_directories(   include   ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}   ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}   ${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS}
#  ${PROPRIETARY_FUNCTIONS_CPP}
#  ${PROPRIETARY_FUNCTIONS_H} )

## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/image_publisher.cpp
# )


#always before add dependencies
## Declare a C++ executable 
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide  add_executable(image_publisher_node src/image_publisher_node.cpp ${PROPRIETARY_FUNCTIONS_CPP} ${PROPRIETARY_FUNCTIONS_H} )  add_executable(image_subscriber_node src/image_subscriber_node.cpp ${PROPRIETARY_FUNCTIONS_H} ${PROPRIETARY_FUNCTIONS_CPP})  add_executable(test_node src/test_node.cpp ${PROPRIETARY_FUNCTIONS_H} ${PROPRIETARY_FUNCTIONS_CPP})

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure  add_dependencies(image_publisher_node  ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})  add_dependencies(image_subscriber_node ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})  add_dependencies(test_node  ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})  add_dependencies(image_publisher_node ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)


## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against  target_link_libraries(image_publisher_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}) target_link_libraries(image_subscriber_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}) target_link_libraries(test_node
        ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290986/qr-module-of-eigen-library-is-not-found,-where-do-i-need-to-alter-the-cmake.txt/) by [mojakobi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30617/mojakobi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can see where your problem is here.

But one quick point first the `#include <Eigen/QR>` is working fine, the compiler wouldn't even try to build your code if it couldn't find this include. So that bit's okay.

The problem is that `completeOrthogonalDecomposition` is a class in its own right not an extra method of the matrix type in Eigen as you're trying to call it.

You need to create an instance of the `completeOrthogonalDecomposition` class templated with the type of matrix you're using then use that class to do the decomposition. Your code should look something like this :

```
Eigen::CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition<Eigen::MatrixXd> cqr(A);
pinv = cqr.pseudoInverse();
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mojakobi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30617/mojakobi/) on 2018-05-13**:
Thank you very much for your comment. You are right it found the include. I just checked my Eigen library version number and found out that I was using the wrong version number. It seems that `Eigen::CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition< _MatrixType >` was added in version 3.